# Simple linear algebra: How to write $A^T x - x^T B x$ as $x^T C x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any way to write the quadratic $A^T x - x^T B x$ as $x^T C x$.

$A$ is a vector and $B$ is a matrix.

In my case all elements of $A$ are the same and $x\in\{0,1\}$ if this matters.

EDIT:
I have read here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.09844.pdf

that $$\max: \sum_i c_{ii} x_i+\sum_i\sum_j c_{ij}x_i x_j $$ can be written compactly as
$$\max: x^TQx$$
where $x\in\{0,1\}$.
Now I am confused as many of the comments say this can't be done unless $A=0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. $A$ is a vector such that $A^T x$ returns a scalar and $B$ a matrix of size length(x) by length(x) such that $x^T B x$ also returns a scalar

Comment: This is only possible if $A=0$. Let's use the one dimensional case. Then you want to write $ax+bx^2$ as $cx^2$

Answer (score 1):

In the special case where $x \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ we have $x_i = x_i^2$ so the maximization problem is equivalent to maximizing $\sum c_{ii} x_i^2 + \sum_{i, j} c_{ij} x_i x_j$ and this is an ordinary quadratic form.